# Hide navbar based on routeparam in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I need to hide the navigation bar based on the url parameters `?hideBars=true"`.

Using `$scope.hideBars = $routeParams;`, this will return `{hideBars: "true"}` I need to be able to hide the nav if the url has the parameter `?hideBars=true`.

The nav has `<header id="header-main" ng-hide="hideNav">`, so that it should be hidden if hidNav is true. However, this does not prove to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$scope.hideBars = $routeParams` to `$scope.hideBars = $routeParams.hideBars`.

Also change `<header id="header-main" ng-hide="hideNav">` to `<header id="header-main" ng-hide="hideBars">`

**Why?**

`ng-hide` is looking for a boolean, but you passed it an object. You also had `ng-hide` evaluating to a different value than was on scope. In essence, it was always `false`.

Comment: I applied your changes, but the nav is still visible with `?hideBars=true` in the url.

Comment: What does your controller / HTML look like?

Comment: I have `$scope.hideBars = $routeParams.hideBars;
    console.log("PARAM ", $scope.hideBars);` within the controller for the pages that this is needed in.

Comment: That's just a snippet. What does everything look like? There is more to this than what is presented. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

*I try to create a sample useful for you;*

Passing `query-strings` in url sometimes comes with problems as `undefined`, **if** you get this kind of error use `spliter` function to get `query-string` **else** just pass your query target to the `$scope.hideBars` to show result.

In this sample we have `/?hideBars=true&somthing=flase&others=12` url, the `spliter` helps you to get the url as `object` like this:

```
{hideBars: true, somthing: false, others: '12'}
```

> **Remember**: inject `$location` in controller

Why **`ng-if`**

if your element is height security use it because it will hide even users select `inspect` on browser, else use `ng-hide` to handle it.

**View**

```
<div ng-if="!hideBars">
    Hide if `hideBars=true`
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $location) {
   var spliter = function () {
       var object = {};
       var splitLocation = $location.$$absUrl.split("?");
       var target = splitLocation[1];
       var splitTargets = target.split("&");
            angular.forEach(splitTargets, function (params) {
                var splitParam = params.split("=");

                switch (splitParam[1]) {
                    case "true":
                        object[splitParam[0]] = true;
                        break;
                    case "false":
                        object[splitParam[0]] = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        object[splitParam[0]] = splitParam[1];
                        break;
                }
            });
            return object;
        }

        var params = spliter();

        $scope.hideBars = params.hideBars;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($routeParams.hideBars && $routeParams.hideBars == 'true') {
    $scope.hideNav = true;
} else {
    $scope.hideNav = false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another, simpler solution. Within the controller, simple use:

```
$scope.hideBars = $routeParams.hideBars;`.
```

When

```
?hideBars=true
```

is in the url, each page that needs to have the navigation hidden, just apply the following style:

```
<style ng-if="hideBars">
#header-main {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```